# SAS Enterprise Guide "Unable to load the children for the item named 'Libraries'" on MacBook M1

Tags: sas

I have a problem with SAS Enterprise Guide (EG) on my MacBook M1. I run Windows 11 on the machine using Parallel Desktop.
I got no problem to use the Data Integration (DI) and Forecast Studio (FS), I can work on both tools for my project.
But on EG, when I try to open the Libraries from server, I will get error "Unable to load the children for the item named 'Libraries'".
I search on Google and found below
http://support.sas.com/kb/65/222.html

It basically said that is due to permission on desktop and documents folder. But I can't any where to do the setup.

May I know anyone encounter this problem before and is there any solution?

Comment: Are you using EG v8.1?

Comment: I'm using EG v8.3

Comment: Hmm... there's a reported issue with 8.1 that sounds like this (which you link to), but not 8.3.  Sounds like a SAS tech support ticket.

Comment: What can I do now??

Comment: Email support@sas.com

Answer (score 0):

According to SAS, EG is not support ARM processor. So can't use EG on M1.

Comment: It would be helpful to supply a link to support your statement "According to SAS...".